# How could I know all the categories from post?

Tags: categories

I need know all the categories from post in wordpress, but my code only give me the first category and I don't know for why. For example: if one post have the category "category1" and "category2" I need know the Id's from those categories.

```
$queryProductos = array("category_name"=>"category1,category2,category3","orderby"=>"title","order"=>"ASC");
$objetoProductos = new WP_Query($queryProductos);
if ($objetoProductos->have_posts()){
   ?>
    <article class="lista-productos" id="listado-productos">
        <?php       
        while($objetoProductos->have_posts()){
            $objetoProductos->the_post();
            $categoriaActual = get_the_category($post->ID);                
            $idCategoriaActual = $categoriaActual[0]->term_id;
            if (has_post_thumbnail()){
                print_r($categoriaActual);
             ?>
                <!--
                <div class="item-producto <?php echo $idCategoriaActual;?>">
                    <div class="foto-producto">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('miniatura-producto');?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="datos-productos">
                        <p class="nombre-producto"><?php the_title();?></p>
                        <?php the_excerpt();?>
                        <div class="saber-mas">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>"><span>Ver Ficha</span></a>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>            
                -->
            <?php   
            }                
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </article>        
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in this piece of code

```
$categoriaActual = get_the_category($post->ID);                
$idCategoriaActual = $categoriaActual[0]->term_id;
```

The first line gets the categories that belongs to the post in an array, that is fine (Just one note, when inside the loop, you don't need to pass the post ID, that is done by default). Your second line of code only displays the first category in the returned array. `$categoriaActual[0]` means that you are only returning the first element in the array, ie, the first category in the array

You can have a look at the example from the codex page of [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category). You can just replace the two lines I've highlighted in my answer with the code below. Modify and use as needed

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
    }
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

> Returns an array of objects, one object for each category assigned to the post.

So what you are doing in your code is just accessing the first object, index 0.

```
$categoriaActual = get_the_category($post->ID);                
$idCategoriaActual = $categoriaActual[0]->term_id;
```

If you'll take a look at the whole returned array you'll see all ids

```
print_r( $categoriaActual );
```

Now in reality you want only the ids, so do:

```
$ca_ids_array = array();
foreach ( $categoriaActual as $ca ) {
    $ca_ids_array[] = $ca->term_id
}
print_r( $ca_ids_array );
```

Or you do it with the WordPress function [`wp_list_pluck()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck):

```
$ca_ids_array = wp_list_pluck(
    get_the_category(
        get_the_ID()
    ),
    'term_id'
);
```

If you for example want a comma separated list from that array do:

```
$ca_ids_comma_sep_list = implode( ',', $ca_ids_array );
```

To output a list of categories it is easier to use [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories), which does return a formatted result.

Comment: `wp_list_categories` is my favorite. Extremely flexible.

Comment: Agreed, most of the time you really don't need more than that, thats how good it is. @PieterGoosen